# Find while error: 'cd: command not found'

Tags: bash, shell, find

Something is wrong with my `find` ... `while` loop . I try to find all folders starting with *Hello*. In every *Hello* folder there is a folder *0*, so I want to change into that folder. But something must be wrong:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "Hello.*" -type d|while read dir
do
  cd "$dir"/0/
  pwd 
  resourcenfolder=$(ls -d *)
  scp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -r ${WORKSPACE}/"$resourcenfolder" root@${TARGET_IP}:/var/navdb/hwr/MS8/
  cd ../..
done
```

I am getting a really weird error. It is the first `cd`  just after `do`:

```
cd: command not found
```

Comment: ok I added maxdepth 1  . So at least that should work. But is everything else correct ?

Comment: That's odd. Could you please [include the complete error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough)?

Comment: Use `"Hello*"`. Only use `"Hello.*"` if `Hello` is always followed by a `.`.

Comment: You should add `-mindepth 1`, otherwise the first entry is `.`  Also use `cd -` instead of `cd ../..`

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend using Bash for-loops to simplify the GLOBing and a subshell to simplify the change-dir activity.  Try this:

```
for dir in Hello*; do
   (cd "$dir"/0/; for resource in *; do
      scp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -r ${WORKSPACE}/"$resource" root@${TARGET_IP}:/var/navdb/hwr/MS8/
    done)
done
```

Caveats: The TARGET_IP value seems reasonable.  But I'm concerned that the WORKSPACE variable doesn't make much sense...